# Ardunio Uart class & Libraries

Tags: c++, arduino, samd21

I am trying and failing to covert a sketch into a library.

Using an Arduino Zero.

In sketch form:

Variable of type Uart is defined as follows:

```
Uart* serPort = &serial2;
```

There is a function that switches between `&serial1` and `&serial2`.

This works.

Now I am trying to implement the same into the library:

Defined in the main code as follows:

```
Sender Sender(Serial2);
```

Here is the header file:

```
class Sender
{
 public:

   Sender(Uart PortIn);

   private:

   Uart* serPort;
};
```

Here is the .cpp file:

```
Sender::Sender(Uart PortIn)
{

   byte data[]={0xff,0xaa};
   serPort = &PortIn;

   serPort->write(data,2);

}
```

This complies but something must crash on startup as the USB port is lost. Reset button has to be pressed to start the bootloader.

I cannot seem to find what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send the argument as a reference or a pointer to the constructer.

In main, It should look something like:

```
Uart* serPort = new Uart();
serPort.setName("COMX");
serPort.setBaud(9600);
Sender s = new Sender(serPort);

....

delete serPort;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks - How would you specify the port in this way?

Comment: @Jeremy I do not know the details of the Uart class, but there should be an argument while creating the object or you could call a function to set the port name and baud rate such as serPort.setName("COM3") and serPort.SetBaud(9600) etc.. Please have a look at my updated result